# Logical same but get different result for hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

What's the difference? The only difference is the place i put the hashmap.get function.

```
for(int num : hashmap.keySet()) {
    if(k==0 && hashmap.get(num) > 1) count++;
    else if(hashmap.containsKey(num + k)) count++;
}

for(int num: hashmap.keySet()) {
     if(k == 0) {
          if(hashmap.get(num) > 1) count++;
     } else if(hashmap.containsKey(num + k)) {
         count++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Wish I had more votes left today.

Comment: Do you actually see a difference in the result, or is this a hypothetical?

Comment: There would be a difference, if not both statements where `count++`. However, like this, there's no difference.

Comment: Those aren't theoretically the same, though. Think about what happens if `k == 0` and `hashmap.get(num) <= 1` in both cases.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Oh, i get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not the same! The conditions under which

```
if(hashmap.containsKey(num+k)) count++
```

is executed are different. In the first one it is executed if k==0 and hashmap.get(num)<=0. In the second one it is not executed.